# Concatenate multiple CoffeeScript before or after compiling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gulp

I have a bunch of CoffeeScript files that I want to concatenate together and compile to JS. Each CoffeeScript file does a specific thing and functionality does not cross over between the scripts.

Currently I am using GulpJS to concatenate all CoffeeScript files together, and then concatenate to JavaScript. This results in one big JavaScript file wrapped in a single anonymous function `(function(){ ... })();`.

I'm starting to find issues with variable names that I reuse between the files since there is no local variable definition in CoffeeScript and each variable is sort of "global" (not truly global, but exists within the anonymous function). So I have to start making sure variable names aren't the same between my scripts, which I think is kind of silly.

It got me thinking that maybe I should be compiling each script and THEN concatenating them together. That would result in many anonymous functions, each containing their variables to themselves, all together in one big JS file. I'm trying to determine if there are any downsides to this.

Is it better to concatenate before or after compiling multiple CoffeeScript files if you aim to output a single JS file? Any real advantages or disadvantages of either? Any pitfalls?

Comment: Could you use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to define modules that you `require`? Requires some work to switch to CommonJS modules but sounds like would solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see any disadvantages of compiling first and then concatenating over doing it the other way around. But as @vesse mentions, you may want to try using Browserify, which should make your life even easier.